# PYTHON: TypeError: DriverSpeed() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python

Hay guise i'm new to Programming, could someone pleas help me i need to figure this out but everywhere i look i don't understand what people are saying... Could someone pleas show me what i need to do, This is the Python code i am working on...

```
def SpeedLimit ():
    SpeedLimet = int(input("Enter Speed Limit: "))
    return SpeedLimet

def DriverSpeed ():
    DriverSpeed = int(input("Enter Driver Speed: "))
    return DriverSpeed

def OverOrUnderSpeedLimit (number):
    UnderSpeedLimet = False
    if DriverSpeed(number) < int(50) ==0:
        OverSpeedLimet = True
    return SpeedLimet

def OverSpeedLimit (result):
    if result == True:
        print("You Are Over The Speed Limit")
    else:
        print("You Are On/Under Speed Limit")

def DemeritPoints ():
    DemeritPointsGained = DriverSpeed - SpeedLimit

#Main Program
SpeedLimit()
DriverSpeed()
OverOrUnderSpeedLimit("number")
OverSpeedLimit("result")
DemeritPoints()
```

i am trying to make something that will ask...

```
"what is the speed limit"

"what speed is the car going"
```

...and then i want it to show me how many Demerit points you will get for speeding 
e.g.

```
"You don't loose any Demerit points"
or
"You loose [number] meany Demerit points"
```

Thank you for your help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def DriverSpeed (): # No parameters here...
    DriverSpeed = int(input("Enter Driver Speed: "))
    return DriverSpeed

def OverOrUnderSpeedLimit (number):
    UnderSpeedLimet = False
    if DriverSpeed(number) < int(50) ==0: # you gave it a parameter here...
        OverSpeedLimet = True
    return SpeedLimet
```

Comment: sorry i'm new i don't relay understand Python that much

Comment: No problem. Remove the `if DriverSpeed(number) < int(50) == 0:` call and replace it with: `if not DriverSpeed() < 50:`